# In C++ language, how do you create a new object which is a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers

I'm using a 3rd party library in which a method is declared this way:

```
void nexLoop(NexTouch *nex_listen_list[]);
```

In case of a single `.cpp` file, this is working:

```
NexButton b0 = NexButton(0, 1, "b0");
NexTouch *nex_listen_list[] = 
{
    &b0,
    NULL
};
...
nexLoop(nex_listen_list);
```

Full example code can be seen here: https://github.com/itead/ITEADLIB_Arduino_Nextion/blob/master/examples/CompText/CompText.ino

Now I'm incorporating this library in a class which has a separate header and c file, so that:

MyNextion.h

```
#include "Nextion.h"

class MyNextion {
   public:
       MyNextion();
       void loop();
   private: 
       NexButton *b0;
       NexTouch *nex_listen_list[];
}
```

MyNextion.cpp

```
#include "MyNextion.h"

MyNextion::MyNextion() {
    b0 = new NexButton(0, 1, "b0");
    nex_listen_list = new ???
}

MyNextion::loop() {
    nexLoop(nex_listen_list); // ???
}
```

I was messing around with pointers and address operators but I couldn't find the right combination to a successful compilation.

My question is: what would you put here: `nex_listen_list = new ???;`

Also, I'm not sure the title well defines my problem. Please correct it if you have a better idea for the title.

Thank you!

Comment: What language is this? Doesn't look like C. Tries to look like C++, but it's failing.

Comment: Okay you might be right. Actually this is Arduino code which is C/C++.

Comment: "A new object which is a pointer to an array"? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: C/C++ ?? what language is that?

Comment: Please, feel free to edit the question to make more sense. I'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not declare a member array without a size. Instead you may declare a pointer-to-pointer:

```
class MyNextion {
   ...
   private: 
       NexButton *b0;
       NexTouch **nex_listen_list;
};
```

And then the construction is easy:

```
nex_listen_list = new NexTouch*[10];
nex_listen_list[0] = b0;
....
```

That is, `nex_listen_list` is a dynamic array of pointers to `NexTouch` objects. And do not forget the `delete[]` when you are finished:

```
delete[] nex_listen_list;
```

That said, if the size of the array is constant, a normal array is just fine:

```
       NexButton *b0;
       NexTouch *nex_listen_list[3];
```

If not, I'd rather use a `std::vector`. Something like:

```
class MyNextion {
   ...
   private: 
       NexButton *b0;
       std::vector<NexTouch*> nex_listen_list;
};
```

And then no `new` or `delete` required:

```
nex_listen_list.push_back(b0);
nexLoop(nex_listen_list.data());
```

And going on, you could declare the `b0` as a full object, not a pointer:

```
class MyNextion {
   ...
   private: 
       NexButton b0;
       std::vector<NexTouch*> nex_listen_list;
};
...
nex_listen_list.push_back(&b0); //use the pointer!
```

No `new` so no `delete` and no leaks.

Comment: This is great help already! I managed to get rid of a lot of compiler errors, however I'm facing with others. Please see my updated question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'd suggest showcasing the use of smart pointers instead of "naked" `new` / `delete`, C++11 and all...

Comment: @papaiatis: You should really close this question and create a new one. Anyway, you cannot convert a pointer-to-member function into a pointer-to-function, they may look the same but are very different!

Comment: @DevSolar: Well, in this case, probably you don't even need the dynamic object at all. But I don't know the used library at all or even if the OP has C++11 available. It is an Arduino after all...

Comment: @rodrigo Sure, I'm opening a separate question for that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

If `nex_listen_list` has static size, you should keep it by value:

```
// Interface
class MyNextion {
public:
   MyNextion() {}
   void loop();
private:
   NexButton b0{0, 1, "b0"};
   NexTouch *nex_listen_list[2] = {&b0, nullptr};
};

// Implementation
void MyNextion::loop() {
   nexLoop(nex_listen_list);
}
```

If the size is variable, you have two choices. If you don't mind dynamic memory allocation, use `std::vector`:

```
// Interface
class MyNextion {
public:
   MyNextion() {}
   void loop();
   void foo();
private:
   NexButton b0{0, 1, "b0"};
   NexButton b1{0, 2, "b1"};
   std::vector<NexTouch *> nex_listen_list{&b0, nullptr};
   void append(NexTouch *t);
};

// Implementation
void MyNextion::append(NexTouch *t) {
   nex_listen_list.back() = t;
   nex_listen_list.push_back(nullptr);
}

void MyNextion::foo() {
   append(&b1);
}

void MyNextion::loop() {
   nexLoop(nex_listen_list.data());
}
```

Alternatively, you can pre-allocate a fixed-size list and avoid dynamic memory allocation:

```
lass MyNextion {
public:
   MyNextion() {}
   void loop();
   void foo();
private:
   void append(NexTouch *);
   NexButton b0{0, 1, "b0"};
   NexButton b1{0, 2, "b1"};
   std::array<NexTouch *, 10> nex_listen_list{{&b0, nullptr}};
   std::array<NexTouch *, 10>::iterator it_el =
         std::find(nex_listen_list.begin(), nex_listen_list.end(), nullptr);
};

// Implementation
void MyNextion::append(NexTouch *t) {
   *it_el++ = t;
   *it_el++ = nullptr;
}

void MyNextion::foo() {
   append(&b1);
}

void MyNextion::loop() {
   nexLoop(nex_listen_list.data());
}
```

You're given a rather powerful C++ compiler. You should leverage it to write code for you. In particular, you should let the compiler generate the code for the constructor.